# PHP inside jQuery issue with ' "

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm messing around with some jQuery, I'm going to try to describe my issue as good as I can, as I'm a rookie. The script is just an example to show the issue I'm having.

```
$( "#activity" ).replaceWith("<?php ifSOMETHING {echo' <div id="hello">'}  ");
```

The issue is, the script uses `" "`, the PHP is using the `' '` for the echo, so now what can I use for the `<div id="hello">` as the `" "` is already used by the `.replaceWith("")`

EDIT: The full code:

```
<script>
$( '#activity' ).replaceWith('
    <div id="chatwrap">
        <div id="content">
            <section class="box">
                <ul id="chat"></ul>
                    <form id="chatForm" action="">
                        <?php if($steam->loggedIn()) {
                        echo'
                            <input id="chatMessage" type="text" class="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Message..." autocomplete="off">
                            <div id="sendmes">
                            <div id="onlinewrap"><img src="img/users.png" class="tooltip" title="Players Online" alt="players online"><div id="onl"></div></div>
                            <div id="wrap_options">
                            <a href="#" class="emotes show-pop btn btn-default top" data-title="Emotes" data-content=""><img src="img/emotes.png"></a></div>
                            <input id="chatSend" type="submit" class="grey" value="Send">';
                            }else{
                                echo'
                                    <center><a href="'.$steam->loginUrl().'" class="grey" style="width:150px;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;">Login to chat</a></center>';
                                    }?>
                    </form>
            </section>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
');
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you can use the `"` and `'` as you want because that it's two different languages, meaning that the php part won't be visible for the jQuery, only the data you echo will be.

Comment: Correct, PHP part won't be parsed in JS side.

Comment: Oh, I'll give that a shot right now then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to, php and js(jQuery) are two different languages and the php won't be parsed in the jQuery part, so you don't have to be afraid of JS interpreting the `"` or `'` only the data php echo's will be visible for JS / jQuery

```
$( "#activity" ).replaceWith('<?php ifSOMETHING {echo '<div id="hello">';} ?>  ');
```

Is completely valid, you still have to be aware of any `"` `'` that your PHP outputs, but not in the actual php code.

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't seem to be working right for me. I've pasted my full code, am I getting it right? (Sorry for the mess.)

Comment: Are you getting any errors @Codey93? Or is the output wrong?

Comment: It looks like it's not closed, whenever '); is on a new line, do i need to compress it all to 1 line for it to work?

Comment: Give me a second. @Codey93

Comment: @Codey93 Okay, it's something to do with the jQuery and perhaps the length / line breaks, but it isn't the `' / "` causing it, I've tested it in my local environment and it works as it should with less data.

Comment: Alright, I had a mistype on my local - but yes it needed to be one line in order to work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with JSON encode.

```
$(function(){

    $( '#activity' ).replaceWith('<div id="chatwrap"><div id="content"><section class="box"><?php echo json_encode('<ul id="chat"></ul>');?><form id="chatForm" action=""><?php if(1==1) {echo json_encode('<input id="chatMessage" type="text" class="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Message..." autocomplete="off"><div id="sendmes"><div id="onlinewrap"><img src="img/users.png" class="tooltip" title="Players Online" alt="players online"><div id="onl"></div></div><div id="wrap_options"><a href="#" class="emotes show-pop btn btn-default top" data-title="Emotes" data-content=""><img src="img/emotes.png"></a></div><input id="chatSend" type="submit" class="grey" value="Send">');}else{echo json_encode('<center><a href="abc" class="grey" style="width:150px;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;">Login to chat</a></center>');}?>');
    });
    </script>
    <span id="activity"></span>
```

output:
when if call

[image]

and when else call

[image]

Comment: Hello GuRu, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I got help from @Epodax to fix this issue. But I learned to use the json_encode with your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$( "#activity" ).replaceWith("<?php ifSOMETHING {echo' <div id=\"hello\">'}  ");
```

Check out [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape it, and replace JavaScript's quotes with single-quotes.

```
.replaceWith('<?php ifSOMETHING { echo "<div id=\"hello\">"; } ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax. PHP has the `json_encode` function to encode content as JSON. Use that to properly escape your data. It will handle `'`, `"`, new lines and anything else you might need to worry about in a string.

```
$( "#activity" ).replaceWith(<?php 
    if (SOMETHING) {
        echo json_encode(' <div id="hello">');
    }
?>);
```

Note that `json_encode` will output a JSON string **including the quotes**, so remove the `"` you added manually to the JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You may use backslashes

```
$( "#activity" ).replaceWith("<?php ifSOMETHING {echo "<div id=\"hello\">"; }  ");
```

I wanted to mention the usage of backslashes. But I admit that using single quotes to avoid this is a better and faster solution:

```
  $( "#activity" ).replaceWith("<?php ifSOMETHING {echo '<div id="hello">'; }  ");
```

Comment: `"<?php ifSOMETHING {echo " /* here it will break it will asl you for + operator */ <div id=\"hello\">"; }  "`

Comment: No it will not, forget your editor, php will know where to start working, just copy and paste my code before putting down please.

Comment: then use 'hello' in place of \"hello\" . it will give error

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro I have reverted back the answer to the initial version. And added a comment, I still don't know Shubham's problem with it.